# How I can detect and prevent memory leak in Java

Tags: java, memory, jvm, microservices

I have the following images showing the used memory and the committed memory.

[image: Memory snapshot last 15 min]

- On the top: used **210** MB and committed **232** MB
- On the bottom: used **10** MB and committed **232** MB

The following image showing the last 6 hours of memory usage.

[image: Memory snapshot last 6 hours]

My Question: based on those graphs

- This application has a memory leak?
- And how I can detect and prevent this leak?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> This application has a memory leak?

No.

> And how I can detect and prevent this leak?

When the low point of the zigzag shape keeps being higher than the previous one continuously, and eventually the VM exits with `OutOfMemoryError`. This isn't happening here - you do not have a memory leak.

Java does not instantly garbage collect all garbage. It lets it build up for a bit, because that's more efficient in the long run.